# why new file from cocoa touch class yield a interface?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

with Xcode version 10.0 when I create a UIViewController from `New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class` and subClass of `UIViewController` it will create a file that not editable and a `(interface)` tail?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the assistant editor. Just change the standard editor by selecting the leftmost option:

[image]

(this segmented control can be found on the top right. If you are in the assistant editor, the middle option should be selected)

Another way to close the assistant editor is to click on the cross (x) shown in your screenshot. Then you can open your new file using the left panel.

You can also switch to your actual file by clicking on the two circles and selecting "Manual -> ":

[image]